# Node.js print "undefined" in a impossible place

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code, every place where something is printed, it goes througth this function:

```
log = function log (LOG, message) {
    if (!message) {
        message = LOG;
        LOG = '\t';
    }
    console.log('@' + NAME + '\t-\t' + resize(LOG, 12) + '\t:\t' + message);
}
```

(The why of this function is not the question and is for formatting).

So every new line begin with @, whatever what data is supposed to be printed after this.

But in my log, I have this:

```
@App            -       play            :       [ 'FC4.mp4',
  'ME.mp4',
  'ME2.mp4',
  'MER.mp4',
  'PvS.mp4',
  'BF3.mp4',
  'BF4.mp4',
  'BFH.mp4',
  'BFH2.mp4',
  [length]: 9 ]
undefined
@App            -       play            :               at 2015-03-17_16-56
```

Commenting out line by line just make `undefined` appear sooner:

```
@App            -       update          :               Done
undefined
@App            -       play            :               at 2015-03-17_17-08
```

There is no use of `console.log`, `process.stdout.write` or other write function anywhere in the code, and there is no character `\n` used anywhere in the code.

How can undefined appear like that? What possible cause can there be? It just freak me out to see this appear in the same place in the log whatever I do.

Comment: looks like `LOG` or `resize()` is undefined.. Do a check for it before your `console.log` function, most likely the `resize()` is outside the scope of the function. (my hunch is based on resize depends on Window reference)

Comment: The most likely explanation is a `console.log` line **elsewhere**, or that something is calling `log` with a message ending in `undefined\n`.

Comment: `resize` is a custom function in the same file (should have said it). I m wondering if it could come from one of the module I use (omxdirector if anyone wondering which)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve calmed down too late to prevent posting a stupid question, but the line came from omxdirector, a npm module that I didn't checked completely before use.

Thanks to you.

(The line is in omxdirector/main.js:

```
var sendAction = function (action) {
    if (commands[action] && omxProcess) {
      try {
        omxProcess.stdin.write(commands[action], function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

Once modified, everything is back to normal)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like NAME may be undefined for one call. You can test it by doing this:

```
if(NAME) {
            console.log('@' + NAME + '\t-\t' + resize(LOG, 12) + '\t:\t' + message);
        }
```

Comment: Even if undefined, it would print `@undefined...`